# Why are some programs writing on stderr instead of stdout their output?

Tags: io, stdout, stderr

I've recently added to my .bashrc file an ssh-add command. I found that

`ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_github > /dev/null`

results on a message "identity added and something else" every time I open a shell.

While

`ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_github > /dev/null 2>&1`

did the trick and my shell is now 'clean'.

Reading on internet, I found that other command do it, (for example `time`). Could you please explain why it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect output from one process to another e.g. via pipes

```
$ procA | procB | procC
```

this is *traditionally* done using stdout. I would expect `time` and similar commands to output to stderr to avoid corrupting this stream. If you're using time then you're diagnosing issues and you don't want to inadvertently provide extra input to a downstream process.

[This article](http://jstorimer.com/2011/12/29/the-difference-between-stdout-and-stderr.html) includes some further detail and some history surrounding this.